# Does Excel have a function to automatically set background colors for values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors

Yesterday I analyzed a files from Torque, an app which logs data from cars and motorcycles. It contained data like RPM, speed, acceleration, throttle position and many more.

To get a better overview I calculated the min and max from each column. Then I set i.e. all RPM values over 9,000 to dark red, 7,000 up light red, and below 1,500 to grey. I did this for most columns, and I did it manually.

Does Excel include a function to do this automatically. I don't want to enter min and max values or say red should be for values 8,000 to 9,000 or something like this. My idea is that such a function detects the min and max values and how often they are in the sheet. Then i.e. the top 10% values should be in one color and similar to other values.
Basically I want to click a button and after that I want to have useful colors for all columns.

Does such a function exist in Excel or as an add-on?

Comment: It is referred to as "conditional formatting" (Main - Styles - Conditional formatting). Study all condition variants available in it.

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting, as @Akina suggested, I would suggest "Color Scales". It will automatically apply color gradients based on the values.

Comment: Thanks. If one of you puts this in an answer then I can upvote it...

Comment: @Edgar, *nothing happens unless the act has not been set to be happened,,,* If you try to use even a Function you need to create an Algorithm that how, when & why an act will take place. I'm sure in recent past I've posted an answer that how to apply Background color to Range of cell using Excel VBA (MAcro).

Answer (score 0):

**This VBA (Macro) code will help you to automatically Highlight Maximum & Minimum values in the Active Sheet.**

*In place of using Hard-coded Data Ranges, the code loops through whatever columns are used and adjusts them for having different lengths.*

*Also, I assume headers in the Active Sheet.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim Myrng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long

ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

  With ActiveSheet
    For lCol = 2 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count

      lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lCol).End(xlUp).Row
      Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, lCol), .Cells(lLastRow, lCol))

      For Each Myrng In rng

       If Myrng.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) Then
        Myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
       End If

       If Myrng.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng) Then
        Myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
       End If

      Next
    Next lCol
  End With

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this VBA code as Standard Module with the Sheet.
- Code will highlight Max & Min Values in every column for the used range in the Sheet as soon you activate (on Mouse Click on the Sheet Tab) it.
- Adjust the Background Color as needed.